# MySQLi query from table1 and update details to table2

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm obsessed with the following problem for weeks and can't find a solution:

I have two database tables. I want to select one row from the first and more rows from the other with MySQLi queries.
The first table named `'users'`, here I store the user current money information. The second table store the information about his `'pets'`.
I have come so far... But I also want to update one of the pet's information by clicking on a submit.

So here's my code:

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT money FROM users WHERE fbid = ?");
  $statement->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['FBID']);
  $statement->execute();
  $statement->bind_result($money);
  while ($statement->fetch());
  $statement->close();

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT clean,health,petname FROM pets WHERE fbid = ?")){

   $stmt->bind_param('s',$_SESSION['FBID']);

   $stmt->execute();

   $stmt->store_result();

   $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

   $stmt->bind_result($clean,$health,$petname);

   while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        if($_GET['buy']=='clean' && $money>='5' && $clean<='95'){
  $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE pets SET `clean` = `clean` + 5 WHERE fbid = ? AND petname = ?");
  $stmt2->bind_param("ss", $_SESSION['FBID'],$_GET['identifier']);
  $stmt2->execute();
  $stmt2->close();
  $stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET `money` = `money` - 5 WHERE fbid = ?");
  $stmt3->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['FBID']);
  $stmt3->execute();
  $stmt3->close();
            header( "Location: /pets.php?success=clean" );
        }
        if($_GET['buy']=='health' && $money>='7' && $health<='90'){
  $stmt4 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE pets SET `health` = `health` + 10 WHERE fbid = ? AND petname = ?");
  $stmt4->bind_param("ss", $_SESSION['FBID'],$_GET['identifier']);
  $stmt4->execute();
  $stmt4->close();
  $stmt5 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET `money` = `money` - 7 WHERE fbid = ?");
  $stmt5->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['FBID']);
  $stmt5->execute();
  $stmt5->close();
            header( "Location: /pets.php?success=health" );
        }

echo "".$petname." welcomes you!<br>";      
if($health<='90' && $money>='7'){
echo "<form method='GET'><input type='hidden' name='identifier' value='".$petname."'><input type='hidden' name='buy' value='health'><input type='submit' value='Healthcare (G$7)'></form>";
}
if($clean<='95' && $money>='5'){
echo "<form method='GET'><input type='hidden' name='identifier' value='".$petname."'><input type='hidden' name='buy' value='clean'><input type='submit' value='Clean (G$5)'></form>";
}
   }

   $stmt->free_result();

   $stmt->close();
}
```

It works perfectly until I click on submit. Then it updates the value at the selected pet, but it updates the value such times as many pets I have. I want to update only once, but I have to print out all pets information in one page.

So how can I do that?

(I can't use `get_result()` because it's not installed on the server!)

Thank to you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the logic for updating the pets from the logic for displaying the pets. You are currently inside the display loop and therefore updates the one pet for every iteration of your display loop. When you move the update code outside the while loop you will update the pet infos only once, but still display all the pets in a loop.

Comment: Okay, that's clear, but then how can I check the value of `if($_GET['buy']=='clean' && $money>='5' && $clean<='95'){` at that pet which was selected? Because here the data comes from the first query.

Comment: @krisz44g You use the `$_GET['identifier']` value like you already do to identify the correct pet.

Comment: Hmm, but if I only do  that and separate the update, then I can't be able to check the value of money exactly before I send the request, so if the button appears because when the page loads I still have the money, but I also open an other window and spend the money to something else, it will accept the request as if I still have the money. This is my problem. Any idea?

Comment: @krisz44g You still have the `SELECT` query to read and check the money the user have. When you have enough money you can check the 'clean' value of the specific pet with a second `SELECT` query for that pet (you use the `$_GET['identifier']` value). If you have the money and the 'clean' value is valid, you run the `UPDATE` query. After all that you still have your normal while loop to print all the pets, regardless if you have run any actions like "clean" or "health".